# refused to load the jquery.csv.min.js Library using WampServer 3.1.7

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is running in the older version of WampServer 3.1.6, but not in the latest version 3.1.7. Please share solutions on how to resolve this issue or how to load my script `csv.js`. I have tried many versions of it but none of them work.

**Bulkdatainsertion.php**

```
 <?php 
    include 'sidebar.php'; 
    include 'server.php';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
         <title>Bulk Data Insertion</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

    <!-- This is the query that is not loading: -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.3/jquery.csv.min.js"></script><script src="https://web.archive.org/web/20160324220311/http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>
  </head>

    <script>

        var data;

        $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
          var file = $('input[type=file]').val();
          var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
          console.log(filename+'hh'); 

          // From here the code is running. We get the filename csv.hh in the console.

          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: filename,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response)
            {
              data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
              console.log(response);
              some(data);
            }
          });
        });

        function some(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $.ajax({
            url:"server.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{data:data},
            success:function(data){
              console.log(data);
              var i=0;
              for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                $('#sno').append('<input type="checkbox" name="s_no[]" value="'+data[i]+'" id="serialnumber">&nbsp;&nbsp;');
                $('#sno').append('<label>'+data[i][7]+'</label><br>');
              }
            }
          });
          // $('#import_form').submit();
          $('#update').click(function() {
            console.log('hello');
            $('#import_form').submit(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
            });     
          });
          $('#skip').click(function() {
            console.log("hello");
            $('#import_form').submit();
          });
          if ($('#skip').data('clicked')) {
            console.log('hello');
            $( "#import_form" ).submit(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
            });
          }
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
          var del = $(this).attr('id');
          var row = $(this).closest('tr');
          if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $.post('server.php?file_id='+del, function(r) {
              alert(r);
            });
          }
          row.remove();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading 2 versions of jquery.csv.js ? And one of them from archive orgs cache ?

Comment: i have used both of them individually but none of them is working.I have commented that script in my code but forgot to comment here.